# can we rename our Rails folders and not have any side effects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rename

when starting Ruby on Rails programming, I will use

rails first
rails second

and try out things in these "first" and "second" projects

but as they get more mature i want to check them into SVN and develop further, so can i rename them into

"superapp"

or

"web30"

and check into SVN and develop further without any side effects?  I don't want to rename them and generate more controllers and models and do migration and one day found out that the project is messed up and caused problem when going to production / deployment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not a problem. Rails doesn't care about the name of the directory it's stored in (or the path to it).

Answer (score 3):

I have not encountered any problems while doing such renames.

In fact I have just created a project and verified that after the rename, the RAILS_ROOT variable is automatically updated. You can verify this using script/console.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to merge, merge them first and then commit.

Rails don't mind about project names so don't worry about that. If you need to rename something already on a svn, don't forget to use the [rename](http://juicebar.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/svn-rename-pitfalls-to-avoid/) function.